# Pine - Having an optional indicator and a required indicator

Tags: pine-script

Can anyone help me with this. I am having a heck of a time finding info on this or sample code to look at. 
Here is what I would like to do in pine script.

minimum of 6 out of 10 buy indicators that are true including 1 indicator that is Required and consensus of 6 or more to trigger the buy condition.

minimum of 4 out of 7 Sell indicators that are true including 1 indicator that is required to trigger the sell condition.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

This shows 2 methods: the first one by adding 0/1 values to a total and then using a logical test, and the second one with just a logical test:

```
//@version=4
study("")
s0B = input(true, "Required")
s1B = input(true)
s2B = input(false)

// ————— Method 1
// Returns 1 when boolean is true, 0 if false.
f_01(_c) => _c ? 1 : 0
buySignals = f_01(s1B) + f_01(s2B)
buyCond1 = s0B and buySignals >= 1
plotchar(buyCond1, "buyCond1", "1", location.top)

// ————— Method 2
buyCond2 = s0B and (s1B or s2B)
plotchar(buyCond2, "buyCond2", "2", location.bottom)
```